# purrr::pmap with other default inputs

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

I am wondering how to use `pmap()` function if I have more than 3 inputs as parameters to map into a function with other default inputs.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
a=c(5, 100, 900)
b=c(1, 2, 3)
ablist=list(mean=a,sd=b)
pmap(ablist, ~rnorm( mean=a , sd=b , n = 9))
```

outputs:

```
 [[1]]
 [1]   5.734723  99.883171 895.962561   5.346905  98.723191 903.373177   4.172267  96.424440 897.437970

 [[2]]
 [1]   4.427977  98.348139 899.287248   4.404674  99.178516 900.983974   3.836353 101.520355 899.992332

 [[3]]
 [1]   4.961772  95.927525 899.096313   4.444354 101.694591 904.172462   6.231246  97.773325 897.611838
```

But as you can see, the output is not mapping the `mean` and `sd` in the order of vectors.

I want to have `[[1]]` with `rnorm(mean=5,sd=1,n=9)` and so on. Out of curiosity, I am wondering what `pmap()` is doing for this demo.

By the way, I know in this example, I can easily use `map2()` without any hassle but in my real code, I have 10 inputs so I need to use `pmap()`.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are using `pmap`, you can refer to your arguments with `..1`, `..2`, etc. This should give you what you want:

```
pmap(ablist, ~rnorm(mean = ..1, sd = ..2, n = 9))
```

Alternatively you can supply a named list with *all* of the arguments included. This works as well:

```
abclist = list(
  mean = c(5, 100, 900),
  sd = c(1, 2, 3), 
  n = rep(9, 3)
)

pmap(abclist, rnorm)
```

Your code is just running `rnorm(mean = c(5, 100, 900), sd = c(1, 2, 3), n = 9)` 3 times and storing it in a list.

Comment: Wow! AWESOME!!! It works! I really appreciate your help! `pmap()` is very hard to understand though. Any suggests to learn it quickly?

Comment: You can also use `pmap(ablist, rnorm, n = 9)`, as `pmap` uses `...` to collect other parameters to pass into `.f`